# Não consigo enviar o arquivo .json

Tags: json, angular

Estou tentando enviar um arquivo `.json` criado dentro do Angular para um servidor, e dá esse erro como resposta:

> "A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]", object_or_array: "object", error_info: "This error came from the org.json reference parser.", validate: false}"

Está apenas indo a URL, sem o JSON, por sinal. Segue abaixo o código, feito em angular:

```
var json={
      usuario : this.nome,
      senha : this.senha
  };

  var myJson=JSON.stringify(json);


  console.log(json);

  return this.http.post(this.url,JSON.stringify(json))
  .map(res=> res.json())
  .subscribe(data =>{
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Se não me engano, não precisa passar o json em string pra função `http.post`, era só passar o objeto direto.

Comment: Tipo isso: ---return this.http.post(this.url,JSON.stringify({usuario : this.nome, senha : this.senha}))---? Eu tentei e deu um outro erro

Comment: Não, apenas substituindo `JSON.stringify(json)` por `json`

Comment: Nao precisa converter pra json, e por favor poste o codigo inves de imagem https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas

Comment: eu substituir o JSON.stringify(json) por apenas json e continua dando o mesmo erro. Teria uma maneira de ver o json de saída pelo console do navegador?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema, era só adicionar no webservice dentro do seu php os seguintes códigos:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
```